# Android,iPhone simultaneous development SCM

Tags: iphone, android, version-control

I was reading up on [SCM](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/software-branching-and-parallel-universes.html) and was curious how it could apply to mobile development.

Would it be possible to create one project for both iPhone and Android and have a branching policy based on technology ? I know the source code is completely different but at least the assets (art, strings, etc.) could probably be shared by both branches.

And is it possible to mix branching policies ? As in branch by technology but also branch by version ?

Any other recommended approach to reuse assets between mobile technology projects ?

Answer (score 1):

A "Branch Per Technology" could certainly make sense, if you're going to be sharing assets.  Also, if you end up with different components, and write some things in javascript, or html, or anything else common to both platforms, it should be shared...

Within each "Technology Branch" I believe you would want to choose one of the other policies, like "Branch per Task" or  "Branch per Component"...

Answer (score 1):

Not reasonable, IMHO. On Android the UI will be, most likely, developed in Java and on iPhone - in Objective C(++). So if you plan to reuse common logic on Android, it will be isolated from the UI anyway, by virtue of being in a different language. And if common logic is distinct from the UI - why branch? Branching only makes sense if the common, iPhone-only and Android-only bits are intermixed in the same file. In case of these two platforms, it's very unlikely.

As for art and other non-code bits, for these, too, the platform domains are no less granular than file.